# McAfee API for ASP.Net

Tags: anti-virus, asp.net, api

Is there any McAfee API [ or command line utility ] that can be integrated with ASP.Net to scan for viruses in uploaded files.

**Edit:**

I was about to ask the question in stackoverflow but thought since it is related to McAfee only it would be better to put this question in here.

***Edit:***

I don't need a 3rd party tool to connect to the McAfee API.

Comment: May I know the reason for the down vote? Is it because of the term ASP.Net? I was about to ask the question in stackoverflow but thought since it is related to McAfee only it would be better to put this question in here.

Comment: This quesiton would still be better answered on SO as it is a coding related question.

Comment: This question has already been answered on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/975112/net-virus-scanning-api/975252#975252

Comment: In my question I have mentioned that I don't need a third party integration tool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After doing a little digging for you, it doesn't look like the Mcafee API is commonly available.

You need to get in contact directly with them if you want samples, however there are third party tools that can plugin to many other AV scanners such as those available from [Opswat](http://www.opswat.com/) which comes with a very good API for many languages.

Edit -

Probably not the best way of going around it, but if you need to use Mcafee (a few other AV's actually provide API's out the box) - You could always just install it on the server and disable all the active scan parts and then just call the scanner exe via command line arguments and wait for a response code - the same way as many download managers, IM clients and others hook into third party anti virus scanners.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can look at [McAfee VirusScan Command Line Reference](https://kc.mcafee.com/resources/sites/MCAFEE/content/live/PRODUCT_DOCUMENTATION/20000/PD20010/en_US/e5200wpg.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the [Microsoft Antivirus API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537365%28VS.85%29.aspx).  It is a COM API that can be used to scan files.  This is the same API that Internet Explorer and Outlook use to scan downloaded files.